# Checkbox form validation in aspx.vb on submit button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hey there can anyone help me or give me an example of checkbox validation please.

I got 3 checkboxes none is compulsory so for instance i get to the page but selected no checkboxes click (Submit button) it must throw a valdation to say Please select only one checkbox and when I select one checkbox and click submit again it must must give a validation message and say you have successfully registered

If any one can help me with this exercise I will gladly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your this library to achieve the same.
Jquery Validation Engine. 
http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoCheckBox.html

Comment: I prefer to do it in aspx.vb not using jquery though thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Then check checkbox value at server side